# SharePoint 2010: Hide multiple selection choice option

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I need to be able to hide a checklist option "None Selected" from the user. Through workflow I have this option filled in if nothing is selected in the choice field, but I don't want the user to be able to see this option when they create an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, a workflow can set a choice field to any value, even if it is not in the list of options. Just remove the "none selected" from the list of options that the user sees.

Here is a screenshot of the workflow steps

[image]

And here is what the form looks like. In the background you can see list items with "none selected" that was set by the workflow.

[image]

Comment: When I try this it fills in the "Specify Own Value" field, which I need available for users

Comment: But when the user creates an item, this won't be an issue, will it? Because the workflow only fills the value *after* the user has created the item, and while they create it, they don't see the "None Selected" in the drop-down. That was your brief above.

Comment: I don't see that behaviour. I've added some screenshots above.

Comment: I realized after I implemented your solution that it doesn't matter if the specify own value field is filled in. Your solution solved my problem, thank you very much!